# jQuery get href attr remove .html

Tags: javascript, jquery, attr

I have the following jQuery:

```
$('.aboutUs a').live('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var clickedElement = $(this).attr('href');
});
```

If I console.log the result I will get page.html. What I would like to is remove the .html but not sure how. Can anyone help? Many thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You could just [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) the `.html` with nothing:

```
var clickedElement = $(this).attr("href").replace(".html", "");
```

Note that if your string could potentially contain other instances of ".html" then the regex answer is better, because in that case, this will remove the first occurence rather than the last. But if that's not the case (and it sounds quite unlikely) then this should work fine.

Comment: In rare cases, this may remove '.html' from other places in the href.

Comment: @a'r - Yeah, I edited that in just before you posted that comment :) If there is a possibility the string contains multiple `.html` substrings, then my example will remove the first only.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a regex to remove the `.html` from the end of the string, eg.

```
"page.html".replace(/.html$/,'')
```